# Automate File upload Test with the button 'ngf-select' using protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am using '**ngf-select**' with '**ng-img-crop**' for uploading images.

Below is the button for uploading images. I am not using input element.

```
<button class="btn-prof-upload" ngf-select ng-change="uploadImage()" ng-model="photo.picFile" accept="image/*" ng-disabled="setImageLimit" id="upload-photo-btn-desktop">Upload Photo</button>
```

When I trigger click of this button, it will open the OS default open file dialog. How can I test this dialog in Protractor? I cannot proceed without selecting an image.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the button to input[type=file] and then set the path of the image file using the following code.

```
var path = require('path');

function uploadPhoto() {
  var uploadPhotoButton = element(.css('input[type=file]'));
  var absolutePath = path.resolve('/home/tessy/Tessy/coach_co/test-coach-
  images/', 'scott_langley.jpg');
  uploadPhotoButton.sendKeys(absolutePath);
}
```

This worked for me!